# How to use GPUImage with Rubymotion?

Tags: ios, rubymotion, gpuimage

I am developing a Rubymotion app. I want to use the GPUImage pod so I add it to my Rakefile and run rake pod:install. But at the end of the process I get this error:

```
sh: /Library/RubyMotion/bin/gen_bridge_metadata: Argument list too long
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (126): [RUBYOPT='' '/Library/RubyMotion/bin/gen_br...]
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/xcode_config.rb:358:in `gen_bridge_metadata'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/vendor.rb:198:in `block in build_xcode'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/vendor.rb:144:in `chdir'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/vendor.rb:144:in `build_xcode'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/vendor.rb:43:in `build'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/builder.rb:64:in `block in build'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/builder.rb:63:in `each'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/builder.rb:63:in `build'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/app.rb:76:in `build'
/Users/jonathanclark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/motion-cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/motion/project/cocoapods.rb:53:in `build_with_cocoapods'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/ios.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/ios.rb:63:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => build:simulator
```

What does it all mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post your Podfile?

Comment: GPUImage works just fine for me. Did you update your cocoapods? What's your build target?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in CocoaPods when there is lots of header files in a pod. I've submitted an issue for it and hopefully it will be fixed soon :)

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1670

Comment: Eloy and I are struggling to replicate it though, if you can provide steps to replicate it, that would be greatly appreciated.